# Take a ScreenShot of my Control - Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to take a screenshot of my control on Winform. I use this function - find in this site :

```
    public void GetImage()
    {
        var bm = new Bitmap(display1.Width, display1.Height);
        display1.DrawToBitmap(bm, display1.ClientRectangle);
        bm.Save(@"c:\whatever.gif", ImageFormat.Gif);
    }
```

But when I'm using it, i have a error about 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' in System.Drawing.dll : A generic error occurred in GDI +.

Do you have any idea aboout that ?
Thanks !

----------------------EDIT---------------------------

Ok I have change my function like this :

```
    public void GetImage()
    {
        var bm = new Bitmap(display1.Width, display1.Height);
        display1.DrawToBitmap(bm, display1.ClientRectangle);
        var dlg = new SaveFileDialog { DefaultExt = "png", Filter = "Png Files|*.png" };
        var res = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (res == DialogResult.OK) bm.Save(dlg.FileName, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

and it's works but I have now an empty picture :/

Comment: Please read ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the code as such looks good. try Grant's advice

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
assuming display1 is a Rectangle that bounds the area of the display you wish to capture.

```
    public void GetImage()
    {
        Rectangle display1 = this.Bounds; // winforms control bounds
        // for full screen use "= Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);

        var bm = new Bitmap(display1.Width, display1.Height);
        //display1.DrawToBitmap(bm, display1.ClientRectangle);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(display1.Left, display1.Top), Point.Empty, display1.Size);

        var dlg = new SaveFileDialog { DefaultExt = "png", Filter = "Png Files|*.png" };
        var res = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (res == DialogResult.OK) bm.Save(dlg.FileName, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

Comment: It works but it make a screenshot of my application and not of my Control - we can see menus etc.
When i change bounds, it start to draw on top left of my screen

Comment: You should be able to get the `Rectangle` bounds of your [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds(v=vs.110).aspx) using `myControl.Bounds;`. Or can you post more code? I'm not able to really recreate your issue from the current posting.

Comment: Did you get it to work? If so, can you select it as the correct answer?